# How do I make the camera app save photos to the SD card right after taking them?

Tags: sony-xperia

I know how to move photos and videos to the SD card, but I want to have it save photos and videos to the SD card in the first place, instead of the internal memory. I need that because I have **very** little internal storage space, only 1.72 GB, and 1.3 GB is already taken up by apps. (Mysteriously, it says apps are consuming 1.9 GB, but I know that at least 600 MB of apps is on the SD card, which has far more space), and when recording a long video, I have to do it in sequences because otherwise, it runs out of space rather quickly while recording, and stops the recording. Then I have to go into the settings app, tell it to move garbage, go back into the camera, and record the next sequence. No time for that? Too bad...

Bottom line, can I set the camera app, or basically anything that wants to save photos, to save the pictures or videos to the SD card in the first place?

Comment: Yes. There is a setting somewhere inside the Camera app ...

Comment: @rjt.rockx Strange. The setting was already, well, set. I am sure when I recorded a video yesterday, it pretty much gave me what I described here.

Comment: btw, Internal Memory is partitioned into Phone Storage and Internal Storage. Might help with that mysterious issue of yours.

Comment: Choose External Storage as default storage in Settings -> Storage. Now, make the video or capture pics. They should be in Sd Card. I too happen to share the same issue when Camera app is supposed to store in SD card but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a setting for that in the Camera App, which lets you toggle the default save location. You need to scroll down for it, though, and that's not very obvious. But, there is a setting for that.

Comment: Note however that setting is not present in *all* camera apps (I've come on several pre-installed ones that didn't have it). In that case, there's an easy way out: [Use an alternative camera app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18931/185).

Comment: But it is present on the stock camera app in most devices.

Answer (score 0):

Open Camera app.
3 square dots at top>
Settings>
(May need Settings again to get 2nd page)>
Data Storage>SD card

Job done !